# What's the alternative to innerHtml attribute in elm 0.19?

Tags: elm

I have an application that allows users create their own e-mail HTML templates via WYSIWYG editor (TinyMCE) and I have a preview functionality for stored templates that shows stored HTML tpl code from the server. It worked flawlessly with elm 0.18. I was showing it using `innerHtml` property.

And now with elm 0.19 `innerHtml` is gone. The only alternative I've found is [html-parser](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/hecrj/html-parser/latest/). But TinyMCE sometimes creates not so valid HTML and the parser fails.

What can I do now?

Comment: With a Web Component? Or Ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no alternative to innerHtml in 0.19. You must either parse the input, like you have stated, or delegate to javascript using either a WebComponent, Ports, or a `data-` attribute and a javascript hook.

Here's a link to the discussion in html-extra that talks about some of the challenges of innerHtml and that it is forbidden in 0.19

https://github.com/elm-community/html-extra/issues/15